# Getting the error invalid option '--asroot' on packages

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, yaourt

When trying to install the package kodi-standalone-service however after I get prompted for editing the PKGBUILD then I get this error.

```
makepkg: invalid option '--asroot'
Unable to read PKGBUILD
```

I can't seem to find anything on this with google. This also happens in the ISL package as well. (BTW I'm using Yaourt to install this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pacman 4.2 was officially released just a few days ago. One of its changes is the removal of the option `--asroot` from `makepkg`, which means that you cannot build packages as the root user anymore.

**The recommended solution now is to build packages with a non-root account.**

You can read more about this change in Allan's [post](http://allanmcrae.com/2014/12/pacman-4-2-released/) (he is a developer of pacman).

There are also some discussions about the motivation behind this change in the [arch-general](https://lists.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-general/2015-January/038172.html) mailing list.

Comment: Is there any way to get around this change?
I always have one shell with su running...

Comment: Many people still complain about this change, but it was done for good...I recommend you to read [Allan's blog](http://allanmcrae.com/). See the latest posts; and, specially, its comments. There are some workarounds suggested in there.

Answer (score 1):

The `--asroot` option has been removed. See the [pacman changelog](https://projects.archlinux.org/pacman.git/tree/NEWS#n57).

So you need to stop issuing `yaourt` with `sudo`...