# How to stop sudo from timing out?

Tags: sudo, yaourt

I update my Arch-Linux system using yaourt. When updating packages from the AUR, yaourt doesn't allow itself to be run as root, so it instead asks for sudo privileges every time it installs / updates a package. I don't mind this too much, however if I don't notice my terminal asking for my sudo password, it might be a few minutes until I check and notice it. When this happens, even though I type my password in correctly, I get an authentication error message, and it asks for my password again a few times, even though it still wouldn't work.

So my question is: how can I disable the sudo password prompt from timing out?

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177460/117549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `sudoers` manual on your system, and search for the `password_timeout` setting (the timeout for the password prompt) and `timestamp_timeout` setting (how long until you will be asked for a password after having used `sudo` successfully). The manual on your system will mention the default timeouts that your system uses.

The default on Ubuntu is documented as 15 minutes for `timestamp_timeout` and `0` (no timeout) for `password_timeout`, but your system probably has another `password_timeout`.  On FreeBSD and Alpine Linux, it's by default 5 minutes for both, for example, according to the `sudoers` manual on those systems.

Comment: Adding this to my sudoers file fixed the problem. Thank you!
Defaults passwd_timeout = 0